# Im looking for a simple mailto button

Tags: php, html, mailto

Im looking for a mailto button that will have a built in message that is emailed to a preset email address.

eg: You see a button that says confirm when you click that button it sends an email message directly from the browser to the email address with a message that says confirmed.

Comment: The browser can't do this directly. It can either open the user's mail client, or it can send a request to a server script that does it.

Comment: this method has existed since the dawn of mail clients time. It's on the Web, I am sure of it.

Comment: Plus, not everyone uses mail clients such as Outlook, Thunderbird etc, so you'd be best to offer them the choice of filling out a form where you can pretty much do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Please note that if you do not use a server, the client MUST have a mail client set up correctly

However do read this: [Using mailto: links for email addresses…what is the practice these days?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/using-mailto-links-for-email-addresses-what-is-the-practice-these-days)

```
<form action="mailto:yourmail@yourserver.com"
onsubmit="return confirm('This assumes you have a mail client. Continue?')">
  <button type="submit">yourmail@yourserver.com</button>
</form>
```